# Where to put txt file when running iOS simulator

Tags: ios

I am building a simple iOS app. And I need to read some data from a text file.
But I don't know where to put it.

I have tried to put it under the Debug-iphoneos or Debug-iphonesimulator. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Put it in the app resource bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag it into your project. When asked if it should be part of the app target, make sure it is. The result is that when you build the app, the file will be copied into the app bundle and thus will make its way onto the target device as part of the app, where your code can retrieve it, along these lines:

```
NSString* f = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError* err = nil;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:f
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                           error:&err];
```

Comment: And here's my full discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_other_resources

Comment: But there is no Resource directory in my project. And how can I retrieve it if I just drag it into the app?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a resource directory. - I've edited to add a little code to show you how to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

The main bundle should work like others have stated, if you want to access it for testing via the documents directory for some testing or other purposes. This should give you the directory for that app:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Resulting URL for if you decide to put it into the documents folder:

```
[[[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE"]  URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
```